# Which is the preferred way of defining an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

As an example, we have this `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sample">
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="myController">
        ...
        <script src="js/modules/app.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in `app.js` we have a module and a controller:

```
var app = angular.module('sample', []);

// controller here
```

So my question is that, I have seen controllers defined in two types, as a controller, and as a plain function:

```
app.controller('myController', function(args){
...
});
```

or

```
var myController = function(args){
...
};
```

Which one should be used and why? I have mostly seen the first one used in Angular-based code, but even in tutorials I have come across the second. I personally don't use the second, as I have read it 'pollutes the global namespace'.

Another question I have is that I have seen this kind of usage for a controller:

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
...
}]);
```

Why do we need the array? Can't we make do with just the arguments?

Comment: Please search on google. There is a lots of blog post in this topic. Such as https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh Do you have another link? That link is full of obfuscated code, and many of the comments have been deleted.

Comment: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide is the best guide as per my knowledge.

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh agree with you. Mentioned it in the answer too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
```

This is done to prevent JS minifiers from breaking your code, because angular relies on names for dependency resolutions.

As for the two styles of controller

```
app.controller('myController', function(args){
...
});
```

vs

```
var myController = function(args){
...
};
app.controller('myController', myController);
```

It's a matter of personal taste. There's no functional difference.

Comment: Part of my question is what'll happen if I forget to include the line `app.controller('myController', myController);`. I have seen people doing that.

Comment: @cst1992: nothing will happen. Your controller won't be defined. Without this line, the function is just a function, hanging out there, unused.

Comment: Won't it be a problem if the scope of the function is more than what app's should be? So the `ng-controller` will be able to access the `myController` function, but anything outside `app` will be too(which should be a problem).

Comment: @cst1992: not sure what you mean there.

Comment: I mean if you don't write the `app.controller` part, anything outside `<... ng-app>` should also be able to access `mainController`, although only Angular should be allowed to access it, and hence it shouldn't be defined as a regular `function`. Is this correct, if you take my original post into consideration?

Comment: @cst1992: depends on how you define that function. Usually it's in an IIFE, so it won't be visible outside of it. If you don't register it with angular, then it doesn't exist.

Comment: @cst1992: "anything outside <... ng-app> should also be able to access mainController" - do you really preoccupy yourself with this? Is it a real problem? Who would write the code to access it if not you? You just don't forget to register the function with angular. And if you do, console errors will remind you.

Comment: And yes, _do_ use IIFEs.

Comment: I was not aware of IIFEs. Thanks for that. And if you can, please move this to chat. I got  a notification, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: @cst1992: yes, can't move it, because you wouldn't be able to participate.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Angular the array annotation based dependency injection or definition is the preferred way:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'greeter', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
}]);
```

See [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

> This is the preferred way to annotate application components. This is
>   how the examples in the documentation are written.

While at the other hand, the simplest way to get hold of the dependencies is to assume that the function parameter names are the names of the dependencies (which is not preferred for like production app).

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, greeter) {
  // ...
});
```

The Angular can infer the names of the services to inject by examining the function declaration and extracting the parameter names. In the above example, `$scope` and `greeter` are two services which need to be injected into the function.

However this method will not work with JavaScript minifiers/obfuscators because of how they rename parameters.

The resulting code after minification will be like this:

```
someModule.controller('MyController', function(a, b) {
  // ...
});
```

So now, the Angular does not know what is the dependency `a` & `b` while if you use the array annotation based, the output will be:

```
someModule.controller('MyController',['$scope','greeter', function(a,b) {
  // ...
}]);
```

So, now Angular can map `a` with `$scope` and `b` with `greeter` and will be able to resolve the dependency.

Comment: Thanks! The part with the minifiers makes sense. We usually deal with full code, so I guess nobody writes them differently in full code, even though they technically can.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is mostly about style, since both methods are correct.
There might be arguments about both ways of defining controllers and other Angular modules. But as it is with every language in Software Development: Find a coding style and stick to it. Inconsistencies are the real problem.
Here's a good style guide to stick to: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

The second question has to do with minification. Please read this article: http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/

Answer (score 0):

#### Syntax for Controllers

The most preferred way for `Angular 1.x` version is to use `Controller As` syntax. Please see code below:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.controllers')
        .controller('HeadController', HeadController);

    HeadController.$inject = ['someService'];

    function HeadController(someService) {
        /* jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;

        vm.logout = action;

        function action() {
            someService.doSomeAction();
        }
    }

})();
```

In your `html` it will be used like this:

```
<div ng-controller="HeadController as vm">
    <a href ng-click="vm.logout();" id="item-btn-logout"><i class="icon-off">
</div>
```

I prefer this syntax. This will let you not to use `scope` in your views.

**Take a look at [John Papa AngularJS guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) - it is good!**

If you are still thinking that it's too complicated and you ain't gonna need it - refer to this article that explains **how to [avoid Scope Soup in Angular](http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html)**.

#### Why do we need the array?

Array with plain text is used during injection of dependencies. This will let you minify your code easily and not to lose dependency names during initialization process. If you are not going to do this and minify your code - you are risking that your code won't work.

Comment: There's nothing about "controller as" in your snippet. That's a different syntax.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yep, I've missed that. Thanks for that, updated answer.

Comment: Still, he asks about syntax for _defining_ controllers. Which is totally separate from syntax of _using_ them.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev There is syntax for both (**define controller and use** them) what is wrong with it? Also I've attached link to take a look in more details. In my opinion - this syntax and usage are the best.

Comment: Your first part answers some another question entirely, not one asked by the OP. He didn't mention `scope` even once! This is still useful info, just irrelevant.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev maybe it is. But I'm still thinking that when we're talking about *controllers* we should mention *scope* because there are lots of problems with it in large code base.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of "scope creep/bloat"? That's what you do here: take a nice small question and expand its scope by orders of magnitude. :)