# Gulp uglify causing AngularJS to not solve provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, gulp, bundling-and-minification

**Although I am familiar with the uglify problem when using Angular**, I started running into this problem again now with a specific directive, even though I am using the array-like style for dependency declaration:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('domainImg', ['Endpoint', function (Endpoint) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $attrs.$set('ngSrc', Endpoint + $attrs.ngSrc);
        }
    };
}]);
```

My main file declares the modules separately.

```
angular.module('app.providers', []).constant('Endpoint', 'http://www.multzfidelidade.com.br/sistema/');
angular.module('app.tools', []);
angular.module('app.services', []);
angular.module('app.resources', []);
angular.module('app.controllers', []);
angular.module('app.directives', []);
angular.module('App', ['ui.mask', 'templates', 'app.providers', 'app.tools', 'app.services', 'app.resources', 'app.controllers', 'app.directives'])
```

Now, when I use this directive, I get the **unknown eProvider <- e** problem

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=rProvider%20%3C-%20r

I'm using like this:

```
<img class="prize-directive-image" ng-src="{{prize.image}}" domain-img/>
```

If I remove the **domain-img** tag, the problem goes away. Also, if I just don't uglify the code, the problem also goes away.

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
    // Concat all JS files into a single one called app.min.js
    gulp.src(['public_html/js/*.js', 'public_html/js/**/*.js', 'public_html/*.js', 'public_html/modules/**/*.js', '!public_html/app.min.js'])
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        // .pipe(uglify()) // Without this line the problem doesn't happen
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));

    // Concat all HTML directives into a single one
    gulp.src('public_html/js/**/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache('templates.min.js', {standalone: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
})
```

I was hoping I could get some insight on where I could have gone wrong in this specific directive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to follow the inline array annotation of DI like for controller of your directive.

**Code**

```
controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $attrs.$set('ngSrc', Endpoint + $attrs.ngSrc);
}]`
```

Comment: So basically the problem was that I had never used inline controller and in this case when I defined it, it slipped my mind. Thank you so much, I would never catch it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the syntax of `controller` of your directive like this:

```
controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        $attrs.$set('ngSrc', Endpoint + $attrs.ngSrc);
    }]
```

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34431659/2405040) for some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can leave it just as you have it now and use GulpJS to do the annotation for you. In my project [SkeletonSPA](https://github.com/elgervb/skeletonSPA) I do exactly the same.

I use the GulpJS plugin [gulp-ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate) to do this for me. Your Gulp task looks will look like:

```
// require gulp-ng-annotate plugin
let ngannotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');

// Concat all JS files into a single one called app.min.js
gulp.src(['public_html/js/*.js', 'public_html/js/**/*.js', 'public_html/*.js', 'public_html/modules/**/*.js', '!public_html/app.min.js'])
  .pipe(ngannotate({gulpWarnings: false})) // annotate angular DI
  .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify()) // do the minification
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
```

This way you won't have to do it yourself and your Gulp task will do it for you ;-)

Comment: I've seen this functionality, but I've really liked the array-style that I get to specify my DIs for myself. The real problem in this question was that I didn't know that the problem was caused by DI because I had never written a inline controller before. Although I don't disagree with your suggestion, I just prefer to keep using the array style.